# Running Symfony2.1 on PHP7

Tags: php, symfony, compatibility, php-7, symfony-2.1

A customer contacted me about their site being slow and that they still run on PHP 5.3 instead of PHP 7. He read somewhere, how much faster PHP 7 is and of course now wants me to upgrade his server to PHP 7.

The only problem I see, is that the Website is running on a old Symfony 2.1 installation. So far, I only found out, that Symfony >= 2.3 will run on PHP 7. Does anyone know about Symfony 2.1 PHP 7 compatibility or has actual hands on knowledge?

If it ain't possible, I'll suggest to update the Website to Symfony 2.3 which hopefully shouldn't be a to big pain in the ass.

Comment: upgrading to symfony 3 shouldn't be a problem. I upgraded myself from 2 to 3 without any problems :)

Comment: What Symfony 2.x version did you update from? I'm a litte concerned, since 2.1 was pretty old and there are already a lot of changes from 2.1 to 2.2 (among other things renaming of namespaces and so on), see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/UPGRADE-2.1.md

Comment: actually it was from 2.2 to 2.7 and then from 2.7 to 3.0 and now to the latest.

Comment: here you can see the recent big changes https://github.com/symfony/symfony/compare/2.0...v3.0.1 and from the official docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html

Comment: I'll then just suggest them to give the update a try but point the "risks" of some broken pages out to them.

Comment: yeah maybe some old controller structures may not be working. but tell them to go versions only in small steps up, so there is no big loose of any not working code

Comment: It will be me, who has to do the update, but yeah I thought about setting up a VM running PHP7, pull the code there, test it, update, test, update...

Comment: yeah. i highly recommand vagrant for your test vm, cause you can simply play around with it :) and i use it too for dev and its awasome

Comment: That was the plan, and puppet as provisioner, since I've already got that setup for other VM's running PHP7 for local development ;)